# Angular Reactive Forms valueChanges - UI changes only

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

The Angular `FormControl` has a `valueChanges` Observable that states:

> Emits an event every time the value of the control changes, in the UI or programmatically.

Is there a way to set the FormControl to ignore programmatic value changes? (Basically the equivalent of `OneWayToSource` binding in .NET)

Specifically, the issue I'm facing is that my `valueChanges` subscription, I'm updating a bunch the values bound to a bunch of other controls, which then causes `valueChanges` to fire for all of them as well, which is problematic as the actions they perform in their `valueChanges` handlers conflicts with the control the user actually touched.

Answer (score 14):

You can skip emitting the valueChange event by passing the option `{ emitEvent: false }` to the `setValue` call.

```
setValue(value: any, options: {
    onlySelf?: boolean;
    emitEvent?: boolean;
    emitModelToViewChange?: boolean;
    emitViewToModelChange?: boolean;
} = {}): void
```

Also you might want to take a look at other options.

> If onlySelf is true, this change will only affect the validation of this FormControl and not its parent component. This defaults to false.
>
> If emitEvent is true, this change will cause a valueChanges event on the FormControl to be emitted. This defaults to true (as it falls through to updateValueAndValidity).
>
> If emitModelToViewChange is true, the view will be notified about the new value via an onChange event. This is the default behavior if emitModelToViewChange is not specified.
>
> If emitViewToModelChange is true, an ngModelChange event will be fired to update the model. This is the default behavior if emitViewToModelChange is not specified.

[Docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#members)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. However, in my particular case, I'm update the values *bound* to the other form controls, not the form controls themselves. So I don't have the `setValue` method available, and it seems Angular's change detection is picking up on the changes and firing the events.

Comment: How to resolve the issue with two interdependent controls having valueChange? I have a parasite 3rd event triggering (for initiator)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass  `{ emitEvent: false }`  as options for the below reactive form methods to prevent them from triggering the valueChanges event

```js
this.form.patchValue(value, { emitEvent: false })
```

```js
this.form.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false })
```

```js
this.form.controls.email.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false })
```

```js
this.form.disable({ emitEvent: false })
```

*yes disable triggers the valueChanges event*

PS:  above `this.form` is a reactive form

Read this excellent post, it'll answer all your questions and even give some great insights on reactive forms:

https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-tips-and-tricks-bb0c85400b58

Answer (score 1):

That may be helpful:

```
    yourControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        filter(() => yourControl.touched)
    ).subscribe(() => {
       ....
    })
```

It will fire only if control was previously touched. It doesnt fix all the issues, but may solve some cases.

Comment: While this is a smell, this actually wasn't bad as a "workaround" until we have the time to properly. When I say "smell" what I mean, is that the _real_ method we had for determining whether or not value changes should propagate is not working. Why isn't it working... who knows!

Answer (score 0):

The reactive form group have property  yourFormName.pristine

You can use !yourFormName.pristine to detect only UI changes

```
 * A control is `pristine` if the user has not yet changed
 * the value in the UI.
 *
 * @returns True if the user has not yet changed the value in the UI; compare `dirty`.
 * Programmatic changes to a control's value do not mark it dirty.
 */
readonly pristine: boolean;
```

Comment: `pristine/dirty` not reset after consequent `patchValue's`, are they?

Answer (score -1):

I could do it by putting this listener on the html file:

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown ... (ngModelChange)="functionToTrigger($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

And on the .ts file:

```
functionToTrigger($event) {
    if (event === undefined) {
        // Put here are the instructions for UI changes
    } else {
        // Put here are the instructions for programmatic changes
}
```

I really don't know why it works this way. I came to this solution by trial and error.

Comment: The $event passed in the ngModelChange is just the value of the model. It has nothing to do with how the model was changed in the UI or not.